# Convert RegEx from JavaScript to Java

Tags: javascript, java, regex, syntax

OK, so I am trying to split a String by ", " which are not inside '[' or ']'. I have a working RegEx for JavaScript but have been unable to convert it to Java syntax.

JS RegEX:

```
/,(?![^[]*])/g
```

Example sentence:

```
ex1 , [ex2 , ex3 ] , ex 4 , ex 4, [ex , ex ]
```

When I try and use the RegEx in Java (under Eclipse) I get an error saying:

> Unclosed character class near index 10
> ,(?![^[]*])

All I did was remove the '/' at the beginning and the "/g" at the end and I have been unable to translate the Syntax.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Update for nested square bracket support

Since you need to also support nested square brackets, and the comma should be ignored inside the square brackets, you need a simple parser to collect the chunks of text you need.

```
public static List<String> splitWithCommaOutsideBrackets(String input) {
    int BracketCount = 0;
    int start = 0;
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<input.length(); i++) {
        switch(input.charAt(i)) {
        case ',':
            if(BracketCount == 0) {
                result.add(input.substring(start, i).trim());// Trims the item!
                start = i+1;
            }
            break;
        case '[':
            BracketCount++;
            break;
        case ']':
            BracketCount--;
            if(BracketCount < 0) 
                return result; // The BracketCount shows the [ and ] number is unbalanced
            break;
        }
    }
    if (BracketCount > 0)
        return result; // Missing closing ]
    result.add(input.substring(start).trim()); // Trims the item!
    return result;
}
```

And use it as

```
String s = "ex1 , [ex2 , ex3 ] , [ hh3 , rt5 , w3 [ bn7 ] ] , ex 4 , ex 4, [ex , ex ]";
List<String> res = splitWithCommaOutsideBrackets(s);
for (String t: res) {
    System.out.println(t);
}
```

Output of the [sample Java code](http://ideone.com/Z2c85b):

```
ex1
[ex2 , ex3 ]
[ hh3 , rt5 , w3 [ bn7 ] ]
ex 4
ex 4
[ex , ex ]
```

Note that trimming items is not necessary.

Also, where I `return result`, you may want to add code throwing an exception rather than returning the `result` as it is at that moment.

## Original answer

In Java character classes, `]` and `[` must be escaped, unlike in JavaScript where you only have to escape `]` symbol (inside the character class).

```
String pat = ",(?![^\\[]*])";
                    ^^
```

Here is an [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/fiBbad):

```
String s = "ex1 , [ex2 , ex3 ] , ex 4 , ex 4, [ex , ex ]";
String pat = ",(?![^\\[]*])";
String[] result = s.split(pat);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

Note that neither in Java, nor in JS, the `]`, outside the character class, does not have to be escaped.

Comment: Note that the original OP pattern matches  a `,` that is not followed with 0+ characters other than `[` followed with `]`. Perhaps, a safer pattern would look like `",(?![^\\[\\]]*])"`, but a CSV parser should work best for such strings.

Comment: The RegEx you posted ",(?![^\\[\\]]*])" works fine if there is only one pair of brackets, ex. var=[some,list,here] but if there are any other brackets inside those brackets the RegEx will break ex. var=[some,list,here[something]]. Do you know how this can be fixed?

Comment: Yes and no, depends on the string itself. One thing is certain: you cannot use a Java regex  to match nested constructs.

Comment: are you sure about that?

Comment: Java regex does not support recursion in regular expressions. It is a fact. Nor does it support balanced constructs as .NET regexes.