# How to find strings outside of parethesis

Tags: java, regex

I read the [***question and answer***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030036/regex-to-match-only-commas-not-in-parentheses) and this is ***not*** a duplicate. I would like to find all comma and split the string by them which are outside of all parenthesis. Consider the following string

```
abc(def(100, test(2, 3, 5)), tttt), 1111
```

It would be splitted then to 2 substrings:

```
abc(def(100, test(2, 3, 5)), tttt)
1111
```

The only `,` which is outside of any parenthesis in the string is ***,*** before 1111.

Is there a way to so with regex?

Comment: I think in general you might need a parser here, especially if the depth of the nested parentheses is not known.

Comment: To quote the not-a-duplicate answer: *Assuming that there can be no nested parens (otherwise, you can't use a Java Regex for this task because recursive matching is not supported)*

Comment: You can't do it with regex, because internally, a regex is build around an automaton with finitely many states. Here, you would have to keep track of arbitrarily deeply nested parentheses like `((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((this)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))),()`

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Actually, it should be possible to do it with a regex -- as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47162098/is-it-possible-to-match-nested-brackets-with-regex-without-using-recursion-or-ba).  Writing the required regex left as an exercise to the student.

Comment: I have already answered the question, see [**this demo**](https://ideone.com/93yjvJ) from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37978758/3832970).